# What is the distribution of $Z = \left| X -Y \right|$ where $X$ is uniform from 0 to 2 and $Y$ is the nearest integer to X?

Tags: probability, self-learning, uniform-distribution

Here is my attempt so far, but by checking my equations numerically, my solution is wrong.

Since $Z = \left| X -Y \right|$, we can start calculating is distribution directly:

$$
\text{P}(Z \lt z) \: = \: 
\text{P}(\left| X -Y \right| \lt z) \: = \: 
\text{P}(-z \lt X -Y \lt z) \:=\: 
\text{P}(\,X -Y \lt z) - \text{P}(\,X -Y \lt -z)
$$

With that, all I need to calculate is the CDF of $\;X - Y$. Conditioning on $\; Y$ we have:

$$
\begin{align*}
\text{P}(\,X -Y \lt z) &= \sum_{i=0}^2 \text{P}(\,X -y \lt z \;|\; Y = y)\cdot\text{P}(Y=y) \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^2 \text{P}(\,X  \lt z + y\;|\; Y = y)\cdot\text{P}(Y=y) \\
&= \text{P}(\,X  \lt z \;|\; Y = 0)\cdot\text{P}(Y=0) 
+ \text{P}(\,X  \lt z \;+\; 1\;|\; Y = 1)\cdot\text{P}(Y=1) 
+ \text{P}(\,X  \lt z \;+\; 2\;|\; Y = 2)\cdot\text{P}(Y=2)
\end{align*}
$$

That way for each value of $Y=y$ where $y=0,1,2$ we have a different random variable with different ranges and CDFs. For each $y=0,1,2$:

$$
\text{P}(\,X \lt t \;|\; Y = 0) = \int_{0}^t \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2} -0}dx = 2t , \;\;\;\ \text{with }\,\, 0 \lt t \lt \frac{1}{2}
$$

$$
\text{P}(\,X \lt t \;|\; Y = 1) = \int_{1/2}^t \frac{1}{\frac{3}{2} - \frac{1}{2}} dx = t -\frac{1}{2}, \;\;\;\ \text{with }\,\, \frac{1}{2} \lt t \lt \frac{3}{2}
$$

$$
\text{P}(\,X \lt t \;|\; Y = 2) = \int_{3/2}^t \frac{1}{2 - \frac{3}{2}} dx = 2t - 3, \;\;\;\ \text{with }\,\, \frac{3}{2} \lt t \lt 2
$$

Meaning that each of those is uniformly distributed within those intervals.

So
$$
\begin{align*}
\text{P}(\,X -Y \lt z) 
&= \text{P}(\,X  \lt z \;|\; Y = 0)\cdot\text{P}(Y=0) 
+ \text{P}(\,X  \lt z \;+\; 1\;|\; Y = 1)\cdot\text{P}(Y=1) 
+ \text{P}(\,X  \lt z \;+\; 2\;|\; Y = 2)\cdot\text{P}(Y=2) \\
&= \frac{2z}{4} + \frac{2(z+1) - 1}{2} + \frac{2(z+2) - 3}{4} \\
&=  \frac{8z + 3}{4}
\end{align*}
$$

So, in calculating the desired CDF we have

$$
\begin{align*}
\text{P}(Z \lt z) \: &= \: \text{P}(\left| X -Y \right| \lt z) \: = \: \text{P}(\,X -Y \lt z) - \text{P}(\,X -Y \lt -z) \\
 &= \frac{8z + 3}{4} - \frac{8(-z) + 3}{4} \\
&= 4z
\end{align*}
$$

Which at this point doesn't seem right. I know I need to reach a uniform distribution between 0 and $\frac{1}{2}$ because this is what I arrived at numerically. But I think I'm not using the intervals of the conditional $X|Y$ properly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your $2(z+1)−1$ should instead be $(z+1)−1/2$. And you have not imposed the required restrictions on $t$, which become restrictions on $z$.

Comment: How can I know the restrictions on z formally? I know ti should be between 0 and 1/2, but I don't know how to arrive at that conclusion.

Comment: One approach is to use multiplication by the Iverson bracket. For example, $$\text{P}(X \lt t \mid Y = 0) = 2t \left[0 \lt t \lt \frac{1}{2}\right]$$